# Using Wordpress Multisite (subdomain), redirect specific site based on browser user agent while keeping the directory url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, user-agent

Here's the situation and what I need it to do, and I can't figure out how exactly to do it.

I have a Wordpress Multisite (Network) set up. My primary site is http://domain.com and I have an rss feeder site at http://sub.domain.com. I need shared links from the http://sub.domain.com to redirect to the same article at http://domain.com (i.e. http://sub.domain.com/2013/02/02/story/ should redirect to http://domain.com/2013/02/02/story/) based on the User Agent.

For instance, readers from every browser except an iPhone should be redirected to the same story on the primary domain.

I've tried it several ways with an .htaccess in the sub.domain.com theme file, but it doesn't seem to work - I don't know if it's because of the domain.com .htaccess file overriding it or if it's the code I'm using.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: There are two sep. codes that I've found in searching but can't get to work correctly:<br/>
<br/>
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`<br/>
and<br/>
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome`